# Bootstrap nav bar background color issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

on my navbar I am using pull-left for an image, when I do this the right side of the navbar turns a different color.

How do I make it so the entire navbar is black?
http://pcduck.com/pirates/index.php

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your navbar currently has the following default styling:

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #222;
}
```

Override it with this (in your custom CSS file):

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #00;
}
```

If true black isn't what you're after and you'd like to keep the true black highlight on the active menu item, your top-level nav list items have a background applied. Remove it to let the dark gray show through.

```
.navbar .nav > li > a, .navbar .nav > li {
    /* background-color: #000; */ /* remove this */
}
```

You'll want to become familiar with your browser's document inspector, which makes finding things like this fairly easy.

Comment: Thank you very much, Can you tell me why the menu is not collapsing when viewing on smaller resolutions?

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments. It's not a good format for either of us. :-)